# Insert character in string before each group of digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that can have this form: `"4 4 8 16 16"` but can also use another separator like so: `"4, 4, 8, 16, 16"` or `"4-4-8-16-16"`.
I'd like to make it into this: `"C/4 C/4 C/8 C/16 C/16"`.
When using `str.replace(/(?=\d)/g, 'C/')`, I get the following wrong result: `"C/4 C/4 C/8 C/1C/6 C/1C/6"`.
Does anybody have a solution? Using a for loop seems to get very inefficient very quickly when the string gets bigger.

Comment: What should be the output for `4-4-8-16-16`? Should it be `C/4-C/4-C/8-C/16-C/16` or `C/4 C/4 C/8 C/16 C/16` ?

Comment: I should have specified indeed. It should keep its original separator to be consistent but it's of no particular importance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace all non numerical values with the wanted parts and while it has a leading space, you need to slice the result.

```js
var array = ["4 4 8 16 16", "4, 4, 8, 16, 16", "4-4-8-16-16"];

console.log(array.map(s => s.replace(/^|\D+/g, ' c/').slice(1)));
```

An other proposal with splitting and reassembling the parts.

```js
var array = ["4 4 8 16 16", "4, 4, 8, 16, 16", "4-4-8-16-16"];

console.log(array.map(s => s
    .split(/\D+/)
    .map(s => 'C/' + s)
    .join(' ')
));
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!